# Highlight zone to be completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my drag and drop game there is a grid that is populated with words that are hidden from the user. The aim of the game is to spell these words with the aid of a sound and a picture. The user spells a word by dragging and dropping the relevant letters onto the grid.

At the moment the user can drag and drop the letter anywhere in the highlighted zone (the word), and the script will slide it into position. This is all well and good but I want to highlight the actual spot within the word where the user should drop the letter.

At the moment the the highlighted word is called ".spellword" and it glows purple. I have created a class called ".spellLetter" that glows white which I want to indicate the space to drop in. Can anyone help?

Here is the script that applies the class to the grid...

```
    $('.drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    snap: '.drop',
    grid: [62, 62],
    revert: 'invalid',
    snapMode: 'center',
    start: function() {
        var validDrop = $('.drop-box.spellword');
        validDrop.addClass('drop');
        makeDroppables();
        $(right).val('');
        $(wrong).val('');
    }

});
```

Fiddle to help - http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/57/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle. In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/62/) version, when you start dragging, the spellLetter class is applied to all possible targets for that letter (droppables with the same data-letter attribute) The statement I added to your drag start handler was:

```
$('.spellword[data-letter="'+e.target.getAttribute("data-letter")+'"]').addClass('spellLetter')
```

i.e find all elements with the spellword class currently active, and with data letter the same as the currently dragged element, and add the class spellLetter to them.

Is this what you required?

EDIT: [Improved](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/65/) so that target highlighting stops when you're not dragging

Comment: It sounds like what I required, but doesn't seem to be working for me. What browser are you using? @Asad

Comment: Firefox. Not working as in not applying the class? Note that until a few seconds ago the fiddle linked to didn't actually have a .spellLetter class defined. It just applied the class; there were no css rules. I edited it just now so .spellLetter has a white background.

Comment: Can you try to edit it on my new fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/63/ I have a few needed changes @Asad

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/64/ there you go. seems to be working for me. There is a problem with dropping in the correct place though, because your script only accepts the letters in order. For "dad", when I drag d I get the first and last letters white highlighted. After I place the first d, if I try to place another d it moves it to the second position, which is wrong.

Comment: Is it still not working for you? I know you can't be using chrome, because I just tried it and it horks up something that barely even resembles a table. The spellLetter thing still works though. What are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox and it still isn't working which is really weird. So when you have the draggable the position glows white? @Asad

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17805/discussion-between-asad-and-smilbz)